# Why isn't lodash installed through Bower chaining calls to sortBy?

Tags: javascript, lodash

To my understanding, if I [wrap](http://lodash.com/docs#_) an object with lodash (2.4.1), I should get method chaining on that object automatically. For example the following code should yield `[]`:

```
_([]).sortBy().sortBy().value()
```

I've verified that this works on [lodash.com](http://lodash.com/) However, when I install lodash (2.4.1) via Bower, the above code does not work since calling sortBy on the wrapped object (`_([])`) does *not* support method chaining.

How come the Bower-installed lodash won't do method chaining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that [lodash.underscore.js](https://raw.github.com/lodash/lodash/2.4.1/dist/lodash.underscore.js), one of the files installed by Bower, is included in my app automatically by [Meteor](http://meteor.com/). This version of lodash seems to behave like underscore, in that it doesn't chain automatically.